# Router Link on Bootsrap React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

Hi so I'm working on a bootstrap CSS header project and I happen to have this issue on getting a link on Bootstrap header that I'm working. I used React router on this one.
If using this code snippet
`<ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link> <Link to="/StoreInfo"> Store Info </Link> </ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link>` I was able to access the router link that I made but then when I inspect it on chrome I'm getting this error in DOMnesting regarding a link cannot appear as a descendant of a link now i fix that by removing the link and putting it inside the bootstrap link instead as show in this code snippet `<ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link to="/StoreInfo"> Store Info </ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link>` but then the problem now is the link no longer working. Can anyone help me to fix this? I will appreciate it a lot and Stay Safe everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems for the *ReactBootStrap.Nav.Link*-component you should use `href="/StoreInfo"` and not `to="/StoreInfo"`

See the documentation here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/

Comment: I really appreciate it! It works Im sorry im confused on how they used the router and the bootstrap thanks a lot for the clarification! You take care, ok. Bless you